# get_object_or_404 only for DetailView

Tags: python, django, get

Im new to programming, im working on a app to study a given topic, and after I read the topic, im showing some flashcards, but I want to show only the flashcards related to the topic, but I always get more then one Deck of flashcards, probably because I'm not getting the correct deck_id. Here is the code:

models.py:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="topic", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('topic:topic-detail', kwargs={
                       "topic_slug": self.slug,})

class Deck(models.Model):
    deckTopic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=510, null=False, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def get_number_of_cards(self):
        '''
        Returns the number of cards in the decks related card_set
        '''
        return self.card_set.count()
    get_number_of_cards.short_description = 'Card Count'


class Card(models.Model):
    parentDeck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    front = models.TextField()
    back = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.front

    def has_prev_card(self):
        '''
        Returns true if card is not thee first card in the deck.
        '''
        first_card_in_deck = self.parentDeck.card_set.first()
        if self == first_card_in_deck:
            return False
        return True

    def get_prev_card(self):
        '''
        Return previous card in deck
        '''
        return self.parentDeck.card_set.filter(id__lt=self.id).last()

    def has_next_card(self):
        '''
        Returns true if card is not the last card in the deck.
        '''
        last_card_in_deck = self.parentDeck.card_set.last()
        if self == last_card_in_deck:
            return False
        return True

    def get_next_card(self):
        '''
        Return next card in deck
        '''
        return self.parentDeck.card_set.filter(id__gt=self.id).first()
```

views:

```
class TopicDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Topic

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(TopicDetailView,
                        self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)


# Here is where i want to get the Deck related to the topic, but get more then one:

        deck_obj = get_object_or_404(Deck)
        card_list = deck_obj.card_set.all()
        card_obj = card_list.first()
        if self.request.method == 'GET' and 'card' in self.request.GET:
            card_obj = get_object_or_404(Card, id=self.request.GET['card'])
        context['deck_obj'] = deck_obj
        context['card_obj'] = card_obj
        return context
```

topic_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="topic-title">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
        {{object.title}}
        </h5>
</div>

<div class="topic-body">
        <p class="mb-0">
        {{object.body}}
        </p>
</div>


<div class="topic-deck">                    
{% if card_obj %}
    <div class="notecard">
        <div class="notecard-nav text-center">
            {% if card_obj.has_prev_card %}
            <a href="{% url 'topic:viewDeck' deck_obj.id %}?card= 
            {{card_obj.get_prev_card.id}}">Prev</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if card_obj.has_next_card %}
            <a href="{% url 'topic:viewDeck' deck_obj.id %}?card= 
            {{card_obj.get_next_card.id}}">Next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="notecard-front">
            <p class="text-center">Front</p>
            <p>{{card_obj.front}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="notecard-back">
            <p class="text-center">Back</p>
            <p>{{card_obj.back}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% else %}

    <p>No card found.</p>

    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'topic'
urlpatterns = [

    path('topic/<slug:topic_slug>/<deck_id>/',
         TopicDetailView.as_view(), name='viewDeck'),

]
```

How can I show only the Deck related to de Topic detail?

Comment: Can you show the `urls.py`?

Comment: Sure. Updated the question with urls.py.

Comment: This is a transcription error, I assume: `context = super(EspecialidadeDetailView,`

Comment: Sorry, that was from another version, context = super(TopicDetailView, is correct on my files.

Comment: @KaueMalpighi: where is `self.request.GET['card']` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `get_object_or_404` is incomplete. You've provided the model class, but not the parameters to get the object with:

```py
deck_obj = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=self.kwargs['deck_id'])
```

`self.kwargs`, contains all keyword arguments from the url. In your case it will contain `topic_slug` and `deck_id`.

`pk` is a shortcut for whatever the primary key is on your model. This makes me not think about how I named it and is resistant to future name changes of the primary key field.

I don't have to worry about `deck_id` not being in kwargs, because if it's not the URL won't match and the view isn't called.

And there it is :)

Comment: Great! I think I understand. But, sorry if this question is obvious, I wouldnt have to pass 'deck_id' to the method on Topic - def get_absolute_url(self): - and, if so, what is the correct way of doing this? Im asking this because it raised 'page not found' now.

Comment: If Topic without Deck can not exist, then maybe you should not have a Topic detail, but only a Deck detail?

Comment: That's really helpful. If I had a topic without deck, I wanted it to display as well, so I changed the ForeignKey to Deck in Topic and it worked just the way I imagined. Thank you.